# RegEx match only strings that are not starting with quotation mark

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the list of strings (in PHP):

a2c

bdR

dDv

"ddv

aaa

"aaa

What's the RegEx expression to match only the strings that are not starting with quotation mark? In this example there are four such strings. So, I need to match four strings only (to count them). For this list I'am using a loop, but I just need RegEx now. Thanks!

I tried with

```
[^"]([a-zA-Z0-9]*)*
```

but it still matching all strings even those that starting with quotation mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the start of string anchor `^`, which means that your expression will match a string if it appears *at any place* inside it. Obviously the sequence "non-quote followed by anything, including end of string" appears inside all of your sample inputs.

This expression will match what you want:

```
^[^"]
```

It simply matches any input whose first character is not a double quote. There is no need to bother with the rest of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
^[^"](.*)/gm
```

(If more than one string is in the variable.)

Comment: i think it should be /^[^"](.*)/m

Comment: What's the idea with `(.*)`? Is it needed at all? Is it useful to capture all characters *except the first* in an additional capture group?

Answer (score 0):

```
$strigs_arr       = array();
foreach($strings as $str){
   //$str         = '"aaa';
   preg_match('/^(?P<string>[^"].*)/',$str,$match);

   $strigs_arr[]  = $match['string'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($strigs_arr);
```